# How to implement a rectangle drag-select script (similar to selecting multiple files in the Windows GUI) with left mouse button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, mouseevent

Clicking and dragging the mouse needs to create a rectangle (box) visual effect. Any elements inside this box should fire an event.

For example, highlighting a group of div elements on the page triggering an event that changes their colour. Being able to see a box effect inside which elements are changed colour.

Also I don't want that default blue highlighting effect to show.

My first (very sloppy) attempt is here: https://jsfiddle.net/hogson/8fav2tjq/2/

```
event
```

I have heard of jQueryUI .selectable() but I would like a solution that doesn't require plugins.